# Laravel Eloquent ORM - Is it possible set default select columns list?

Tags: php, laravel-4, orm, eloquent

In much of db queries I did not need all data, so I do the following

```
User::get(array('id', 'first_name', 'email'));
```

Is it possible set to select by default ('id', 'first_name', 'email') columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Eloquent Query Scope](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#query-scopes) Scopes allow you to easily re-use query logic in your models. To define a scope, simply prefix a model method with scope

For example in your `User` model add this method

```
public function scopeFetch($query, $columns = array('id', 'first_name', 'email'))
{
    return $query->get($columns);
}
```

and call it this way

```
User::fetch();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define a scope function inside your model class.

```
public function scopeGetData($query)
{
    return $query->select(['id', 'first_name', 'email']);
}
```

you can call this scope in your controller function like this

```
User::GetData()->get();
```